# why does log scale does not start at 0

Tags: linear, logarithm, curves

[image]I need help in understanding the curve shown in the image. As you can see in the image that I-V curves in (a) is for linear scale and it shows 0 Amps at 0 Volts. But for logarithm scale I-V curves in (b) the curve does not converge at 0. I know that it is a log scale, but I still cannot understand it fully. I will appreciate if you can please explain it a little more.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The logarithm $\log(I(V))$ is only defined for $I(V) > 0$, so they probably first took the absolute value $|I(V)|$ and then removed all the points where $I(V) = 0$. Note, that with $|I(V)|\to_+ 0$ you have $\log |I(V)| \to -\infty$. See e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm). That's why you see some of the curves in the logarithmic scale dive down towards $-\infty$.

In general, taking the logarithm is like zooming in to very small positive values. That way, you can see what really happens. And curves that might all converge to zero might have different behaviors in this "zoomed in" picture.

Consider e.g.:
$$
\begin{align}
I_1(V) &= \frac{1}{x}\quad \mbox{and} \\
I_2(V) &= \frac{1}{x^2}.
\end{align}
$$
Both converge to zero for $V\to\infty$, in particular, they converge to each other. But that is not true for their logarithms:

$$
\begin{align}
\log I_1(V) &= \log\frac{1}{x}\\
            &= - \log x\\
\log I_2(V) &= \log\frac{1}{x^2}\\
            &= -2 \log x\\
            &= 2 \log I_1(V).
\end{align}
$$

Thus, the logarithms do not converge to each other; in fact, their distance gets larger and larger.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation I understand it now. However, I don't think they might have removed the points at I(V)=0 because even when I plot the curve with logarithm scale (please read it as using an instrument which has logarithm circuit for measureing the I-V curves), I did not get the curve converging at 0. That is the reason why I want to understand why. I have attached the image.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by "the curve converging at 0," but in all the plots you can take absolute currents of $10^{-15}$ as being essentially zero (it's over nine orders of magnitude less than the largest currents).  After all, a log scale is incapable of showing true zero: that would be located infinitely below the origin.

Comment: I mean to say that the curve does not converge or point at 0 Volts but at -0.1Volts. I hope I explained it correctly. Please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Isn't that a matter for the data to decide?  Nothing in statistical theory or practice will tell us how measurements of voltage and current must behave.  I emphasize *measurements* here, because even if physical theory tells you they must simultaneously be zero, your measurement system might tell you otherwise.

Comment: that's right. Thank you again.